# iOS - Sqlite query returning results from array in 0x00 format with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, sqlite, utf-8

I'm trying to display in a label the results of a sqlite query. I try to put the datas into an array and converting the rows to NSStrings, but the results are still displayed in 0x00 format as result of the const char. I'm unable to convert them to NSString.

```
-(void)getSQLiteData:(NSString *)dbPath {
    sqliteData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    sqlite3 *database;
    if (sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        const char *sql = "select Name, Email, Account from People";

        sqlite3_stmt *selectStatement;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            while(sqlite3_step(selectStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                peopleObject *peopleObject = [[peopleObject alloc] init];
                peopleObject.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 0)];
                peopleObject.email = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 1)];
                peopleObject.account = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectStatement, 2)];
                [sqliteData addObject:peopleObject];
            }
        }
    }
    NSLog (@"%@", sqliteData);

    txtTxt.numberOfLines = 0;
    txtTxt.text = [sqliteData componentsJoinedByString:@", "];

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

NSLog returns:

```
"2016-09-17 17:03:17.424 test2000[3533:292683]
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023cf40>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023cf80>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023cfc0>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023d020>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023d060>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023d000>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023d0c0>",
    "<PeopleObject: 0x60800023d100>"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "0x00 format"? Update your question with the actual output from the line `NSLog (@"%@", sqliteData);`.

Comment: I mean that the results displayed in the UILabel are : <Object:00x6000022ecc0>, etc.

Comment: As I said, update your question (don't post a comment) showing the log output.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for `NSArray componentsJoinedByString:`:

> Each element in the array must handle `description`.

You are trying to convert instances of your `peopleObject` class into strings. In order for this to work, your `peopleObject` class must implement a useful version of the `description` method.

One possible implementation (added to peopleObject.m) could be:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name: %@, email: %@, account: %@", self.name, self.email, self.account];
}
```